# configuring config.yaml:8:18 with error in incosistent indentation in ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: server

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      addresses:[192.168.0.243/24,]
      dhcp:no
      gateway4:192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:[192.168.0.1,8.8.8.8]
```

it displays the error of inconsistent indentation at the nameservers: with the arrow at the colon.
I have tried different indentations but it did not work
pls help..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several incorrect items in your yaml file. I suggest that you consult:

```
cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static.yaml
```

Carefully amend your yaml to match:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.243/24
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.0.1,8.8.8.8]
```

Proofread carefully twice. Save and close the text editor. Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Comment: thanks.. I also had 01-netcfg.yaml that was bringing about a conflict to my undersatnding